# How can I import a specific value from a dictionary from another page in python?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to import a specific value from a dictionary in another page in python:
In this example **alert_rule_dict['pop2']** - pop2 is a data frame and I want to import it specifically to another page and not the whole dictionary.

Anyway?

Thanks in advance!

````
%run pop_divition.ipynb
from pop_divition import alert_rule_dict['pop2'] ```
````

Answer (score 0):

while it is not possible to import an element with the import statement, you can just import that dictionary then take what you want then delete the dictionary, which is equivalent to what you are trying to acheive.

```py
from pop_divition import alert_rule_dict
pop2 = alert_rule_dict['pop2']
del alert_rule_dict
```

just a small note that this is not going to save you any memory or time, as the dictionary is created and saved into memory in the `from pop_divition import x`, and isn't ever removed from memory, unless you remove it yourself, so you are just better off not using the del anyway.

Comment: Yes my issue is that i'm trying to save memory and time. So this solution doesn't help, but thank you very much for your assistance.

Comment: @AmitayAuerbach then your only option is to save the data inside a database instead of a `.py` file, and only load the data you want when you need it (with caching to only read data from disk once)